# Where is the System Restore on Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, system-restore

I have Windows Server 2012 Standard Edition and would like to use [Windows System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/system-restore). But, I can't find it.

Trying to start it using the Windows Run command `restore` didn't work. I can't find it in System Settings. And I couldn't find it in the the Windows folders "System32" or "SysWOW64".

**So my question is: Where is "System Restore"? Do I need to install it manually via Server Manager? etc....**

Comment: Doesn't exist on `Windows Server OS`.

Answer (score 10):

Windows System Restore is a workstation operating system feature (e. g. Windows 7) and as such is not found on any of the Microsoft Server Operating Systems, including Windows Server 2012, 2016, or 2019.

However, the server operating systems include the  [Windows Server Backup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770757.aspx) feature which can be used to create full backups of the system, or a *System State* backup which is quite similar to a Restore Point created by Windows System Restore.

Comment: System Restore is a user friendly **workstation** replication of what backing up `System State` with `Windows System Backup` does. You may not want to "create a backup" but that is what you need to do on Windows Server OS. The alternative is to get an aftermarket backup software package, which often is quite expensive.